# Using XSL to obtain attribute value elsewhere in XML document

Tags: xslt, xpath, cruisecontrol.net, stylesheet

I run CruiseControl.NET and am trying to construct an XSL stylesheet that extracts certain information about broken unit tests from the XML build log. For each broken unit test, I would like to obtain in XSL the unit test's name, the class name in which the unit test resides, and the failure message. Currently, I can obtain the unit test name and failure message, but I am having trouble obtaining the class name.  I think this is because the unit test's class name is only contained in a different area of the XML build log, and I am a noob at XSL.  Here is a pared-down sample of my XSL stylesheet:

```
<!-- Unit tests -->
<xsl:template match="/">
 <table border="1" width="100%">
  <tr>
   <th align="left">Class</th>
   <th align="left">Method</th>
   <th align="left">Message</th>
  </tr>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="/cruisecontrol/build/*[local-name()='TestRun']/*[local-name()='Results']/*[local-name()='UnitTestResult']"/>
 </table>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Failed uint test -->
<xsl:template match="*[local-name()='UnitTestResult'][@outcome='Failed']">
 <tr>
  <td>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="/cruisecontrol/build/*[local-name()='TestRun']/*[local-name()='TestDefinitions']/*[local-name()='UnitTest'][@id=@testId]"/>
  </td>
  <td>
   <xsl:value-of select="@testName"/>
  </td>
  <td>
   <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='Output']/*[local-name()='ErrorInfo']/*[local-name()='Message']"/>
  </td>
 </tr>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Failed unit test class name -->
<xsl:template match="/cruisecontrol/build/*[local-name()='TestRun']/*[local-name()='TestDefinitions']/*[local-name()='UnitTest']">
 <xsl:value-of select="@className"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Here is a pared-down sample XML build log:

```
<cruisecontrol>
 <build>
  <TestRun>
   <TestDefinitions>
    <UnitTest name="MyUnitTest" storage="Test.dll" id="b17e5b2a-47d0-5f78-1750-07c8ac14518c">
     <TestMethod className="UnitTests.cs" name="MyUnitTest" />
    </UnitTest>
    ...
   </TestDefinitions>
   <Results>
    <UnitTestResult testId="b17e5b2a-47d0-5f78-1750-07c8ac14518c" testName="MyUnitTest" outcome="Failed">
     <Output>
      <ErrorInfo>
       <Message>Assert.AreEqual failed</Message>
      </ErrorInfo>
     </Output>
    </UnitTestResult>
    ...
   </Results>
  </TestRun>
 </build>
</cruisecontrol>
```

Here is the current output:

> Unit test class name:
>
> Unit test method name: MyUnitTest
>
> Failure message: Assert.AreEqual failed

Here is the desired output:

> Unit test class name: UnitTests.cs
>
> Unit test method name: MyUnitTest
>
> Failure message: Assert.AreEqual failed

My problem is that the class name is always empty.  I am trying to use the testId attribute of the UnitTestResult node to reference the correct UnitTest node elsewhere in the document.  What XSL or Xpath magic do I need to accomplish my goal?

Comment: Why are you using those `local-name()` instead of direct node names? Assuming that there are no XML namespaces (at least there are none in the XML you posted), `/cruisecontrol/build/TestRun/Results/UnitTestResult` would be equivalent to `/cruisecontrol/build/*[local-name()='TestRun']/*[local-name()='Results']/*[local-name()='UnitTestResult']`.

Comment: I'm not really sure; I am a pretty big noob at this and am picking up with someone else's previous work.  Thanks for the help and comment; will take a look at changing that.  I am definitely open to further suggestions on cleaning things up and adopting better practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance it looks like this is your problem:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/cruisecontrol/build/*[local-name()='TestRun']/*[local-name()='TestDefinitions']/*[local-name()='UnitTest'][@id=@testId]"/>
```

Specifically, the `[@id=@testId]` part. You're trying to look up a `UnitTest` based on its `id` attribute from the `testid` attribute of a `UnitTestResult`. The problem is in this context `[@id=@testId]` means "look for UnitTest elements whose id and testId attributes match."

What you really want is to use the [`current()`](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/func_current.asp) function, which allows you to have more than one context within a filter, like this:

```
[@id=current()/@testId]
```

Also, like Lucero commented, you'll want to remove your `local-name()` calls since it'll make everything simpler:

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
  select="/cruisecontrol/build/TestRun/TestDefinitions/UnitTest[@id=current()/@testId]"
/>
```

As an alternative to using a long XPath expression for your lookups you can use [keys](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_key.asp) instead. They let you define a key, which you can use for shorter lookups later.

Define a key like this:

```
<xsl:key 
  name="tests" 
  match="/cruisecontrol/build/TestRun/TestDefinitions/UnitTest" 
  use="@id"/>
```

Then use it like this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('tests',@testId)"/>
```

That saves you from having to use the current() function. Either way it'll work.

---

Using the `local-name()` function might indicate that you have a namespace problem. If the `build` and `TestRun` elements are in different namespaces, you can't simply query them by using `/cruisecontrol/build/TestRun/`. That will query elements from the default namespace only. If `TestRun` is in another namespace, you'll need to define that namespace in the XSLT file and use its prefix in your expressions, like this: `/cruisecontrol/build/ns:TestRun` where `ns` is the namespace prefix in question. What `local-name()` does is it ignores the namespace part of an element's name, bypassing defining the namespace properly. It's also useful when you don't know what namespace(s) are going to be used in the source document.

Comment: Interesting; the <TestRun> node is a child of the <build> node.  The build node does not specify a namespace, but the TestRun node does:

xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2006"

Does that mean they are in different namespaces?

Comment: @Dark Lord: yes. xmlns="foo" is a *default namespace declaration*, meaning that this and all descendant elements that do not have a namespace prefix are in the "foo" namespace. Therefore `<TestRun>` is in the TeamTest namespace but `<build>` is not.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Welbog and LarsH, I got it working as intended.  There were namespace problems which I overcame by defining the TeamTest namespace at the top of the stylesheet.  In addition to that, I had to fiddle with using the namespace along with the local-name function for nodes below that namespace.  It was glorious to see it work.  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: +1 For "use keys" answer. @Dark Lord Kvl: Whenever there is cross reference you should use keys. As a minor: the `xsl:key/@match` expect a pattern expression; it's a good practice to use relative patterns (i.e. `match="UnitTest"` should be enough in this case).